# Running cygwin compiled program from Java

Tags: java, cygwin

I have built an .exe using cygwin. It is called ms.exe. I am trying to run it from java using ProcessBuilder. I have used ProcessBuilder before to capture its output.

On a command window (cmd.exe), if I run ms.exe [ms-params] > output.txt. Then output contains

> /cygdrive/c/my-path-to-ms.exe [msparams]
>
> > [program output]

On the command window, if I do not pass any redirection i.e., > output.txt, then output consists of only [program output].

Note that I have %CYGWIN_HOME%/bin under my PATH env variable.

Calling ProcessBuilder with ms.exe ends (witout any exception) but as output I only get

> /cygdrive/c/my-path-to-ms.exe [msparams]

Comment: How do you read from the `Stream`? Have you checked the error stream as well as the stdout stream?

Comment: I can read from process.getInputStream but the result is the same that I get a single line. I have simplified the code to just use processBuilder.redierctOutput to write out to a file. The file ends up with the same one line. I am catching for mandatory IoException and InterruptedException, but nothing there. My guess is that when I run from command line, bash is involved.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe","/C","entire-exe-path-with-arguments")` runs the executable.

I have another executable that works when used as`ProcessBuilder("exe-path","arg1","arg2"..)`.

I am not sure why the former execuatble runs only under cmd.

Both were built using cygwin. I have tried placing cygwin1.dll in the working directory without any effect.